# Plotting multiple polar line graphs using plotly express

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am trying to plot 3 polar line graphs in one figure using plotly express. While I can get each individual figure to work, I get errors when trying to plot all 3 as subplots. I am new to plotly express and so am a little confused as to how the subplots work.

Below are two separate attempts each receiving their own errors. If anyone can help sort one of these out I would really appreciate it.

For reference, my df's look like this

```
Indicator   variable    value
0   Extreme Poverty Agriculture 0.154194
1   Extreme Poverty WASH    0.103432
2   Extreme Poverty Governance  0.383699
3   Extreme Poverty Demographics    0.164442
4   Extreme Poverty Education   0.017159
5   Extreme Poverty Conflict    0.177073
```

First Attempt

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(311)

#Figure 1
fig = px.line_polar(Xmelt,
                   r="value", 
                   theta="variable",
                   color="Indicator",
                   line_close=True,
                   range_r = [0, 0.4],
                   title ='2025',
                   width=800,
                   height=500,
                   color_discrete_sequence=('#520e05','#898989','#dbd91d'))
                   #color_discrete_sequence= px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.update_layout(
    polar_radialaxis_ticksuffix='%',
    polar_angularaxis_rotation=90)


#Figure 2
fig = px.line_polar(Hmelt,
                   r="value", 
                   theta="variable",
                   color="Indicator",
                   line_close=True,
                   range_r = [0, 0.4],
                   title ='2025',
                   width=800,
                   height=500,
                   color_discrete_sequence=('#520e05','#898989','#dbd91d'))
                   #color_discrete_sequence= px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.update_layout(
    polar_radialaxis_ticksuffix='%',
    polar_angularaxis_rotation=90)


#Figure 3
#ax3 = fig.add_subplot(133)
fig = px.line_polar(Cmelt, 
                   r="value", 
                   theta="variable",
                   color="Indicator",
                   line_close=True,
                   range_r = [0, 0.6],
                   title ='2025',
                   width=800,
                   height=500,
                   color_discrete_sequence=('#520e05','#898989','#dbd91d'))
                   #color_discrete_sequence= px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.update_layout(
    polar_radialaxis_ticksuffix='%',
    polar_angularaxis_rotation=90)
```

Attempt 1: no error here but only the last graph appears

Second Attempt

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, specs=[{'type': 'polar'}])
trace1 = go.Scatterpolar(
                   r=Xmelt["value"], 
                   theta=Xmelt["variable"],
                   color=Xmelt["Indicator"],
                   line_close=True,
                   range_r = [0, 0.4],
                   title ='2025',
                   width=800,
                   height=500,
                   color_discrete_sequence=('#520e05','#898989','#dbd91d') , row=3, col=1)
                   #color_discrete_sequence= px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)), 3, 1)                             
                            
trace2 = go.Scatterpolar(
                   r=Hmelt["value"],  
                   theta=Hmelt["variable"],
                   color=Hmelt["Indicator"],
                   line_close=True,
                   range_r = [0, 0.4],
                   title ='2025',
                   width=800,
                   height=500,
                   color_discrete_sequence=('#520e05','#898989','#dbd91d') , row=3, col=2)
                              
                              
trace3 = go.Scatterpolar(
                   r=Cmelt["value"], 
                   theta=Cmelt["variable"],
                   color=Cmelt["Indicator"],
                   line_close=True,
                   range_r = [0, 0.6],
                   title ='2025',
                   width=800,
                   height=500,
                   color_discrete_sequence=('#520e05','#898989','#dbd91d') , row=3, col=3)

fig.show()
```

Attempt 2: the error message here is: The 'specs' argument to make_subplots must be a 2D list of dictionaries with dimensions (3 x 1).
Received value of type <class 'list'>: [{'type': 'polar'}]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't you need to specify the plotly library, I don't know if you can do subplots in express.
Second, the graph type for make_subplot needs to be in list format and the number of plots needed needs to be specified.

1st Attempt:

```
import plotly.expess as px
```

2nd Attempt:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, specs=[[{'type': 'polar'}]*3])
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. 

On the second point, I still get the same error message after including your edits: "The 'specs' argument to make_subplots must be a 2D list of dictionaries with dimensions (3 x 1).
    Received value of type <class 'list'>: [[{'type': 'polar'}, {'type': 'polar'}, {'type': 'polar'}]]"

Is there a problem with the underlying data? Or is the problem still with the code?
Thanks for any further comments.

Comment: You need to make it a multiple list, so please set it as follows. `specs=[[{'type': 'polar'}],[{'type': 'polar'}],[{'type': 'polar'}]]`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Running the code now throws the error: 

Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Scatterpolar: 'color'

Comment: If you look at the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatterpolar/), you'll see that it says "specific color name" or "array of numbers", so I guess you can't use a string as a category variable. You can try removing the color specification.

Comment: Tried that and ended up running into a chain of errors flagging different components. After removing each components as the errors came up it eventually passed one large empty plot. Plotly doesnt seem too good for making subplots but thats ok I've found a workaround for my project.

Thanks for your time!